# My Wikipedia code doesn't work properly

Tags: python, rss, python-3.5

I'm a total noob to Python, and for some (probably obvious) reason, my code won't work as I want. Here it is:

```
import feedparser
import time

feed = feedparser.parse('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:NewPages&feed=rss')
latest = feed.entries[0].title
current = latest

print(current)

while True:
    latest = feed.entries[0].title
    if current != latest:
        current = latest
        print(current)
    time.sleep(5)
```

What it's meant to do is print every time the wikipedia RSS feed updates. However, it only ever prints out the latest once (presumable at the print statement before the while statement). Is this just a logic error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only ever request the feed once, at the beginning of your script. You never update it within the while loop, so naturally the condition is never true.

Instead you should move the lines that request and parse the feed into the loop itself.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that I needed to update the feed. I supposed that it would do it automatically. Pretty naive of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line in the while loop.

```
feed.update
```